# convert/combine 2 column dataframe to 1 column dataframe- R

Tags: r

The script below shows X, Y data that is stored in a two columns data.frame

```
a1 <- as.character(c(3456,2569))
a2 <- as.character(c(956,569))
a3 <- as.character(c(156,269))
mydf <- rbind(a1, a2, a3)
```

How can I stored it in a data.frame with one column in the  format “X,Y” and add zero to each X and Y (characters).

so the output will be

```
"3456.000, 2569.000"
"956.000, 569.000"
"156.000, 269.000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
data.frame(col1 = apply(mydf, 1, function(x) paste(paste0(x, '.000'), collapse = ', ')))
#                 col1
#a1 3456.000, 2569.000
#a2   956.000, 569.000
#a3   156.000, 269.000
```

`apply` iterates per row of your matrix and firstly creates the number with the zeroes (that's `paste0`) and then merges everything in one comma separated string (that's `paste`).

Answer (score 1):

Are all the numbers integers, or do some of them already have a decimal point? If it's the latter, you might want to do something like

```
sprintf("%.3f, %.3f", as.numeric(mydf[,1]), as.numeric(mydf[,2]))
```